# PowerMockito Spy: Calling real method results with CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mocking, powermockito

I'm starting to bang my head against the wall, but I completely don't understand how to call real method on spied class.

Long story short, I'm spying on my tested class to stub one private method. Then I want to call real void method of tested class but it says that

> 'testedMethod' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!

The problem is that I don't need it to be stubbed. I have tried doCallRealMethod() as well, no use.

I'm using Kotlin and Android Studio to run some unit tests for my Android project. I have following class that I want to test:

```
class MyClass {
   fun persistDeviceData(deviceInfo: DeviceInfo, saveCallback: SaveCallback) {
       val deviceObject = getDeviceObject()
          // some setters from deviceInfo here
       deviceObject.saveInBackground(callback)
   }

   // This method is created for unit testing purposes
   private fun getDeviceObject(): MyDeviceObject{
       return MyDeviceObject("someStringArgument")
   }
}
```

And here is testing class

```
import io.kotlintest.KTestJUnitRunner
import io.kotlintest.specs.BehaviorSpec
import junit.framework.Assert
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.mockito.Mockito

import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunnerDelegate

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(KTestJUnitRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass::class)
class MyClassTest: BehaviorSpec(){

    init {

        val deviceObject = PowerMockito.mock(MyDeviceObject::class.java)
        val myClassTest = PowerMockito.spy(MyClass())
        // Mocking private method call
        PowerMockito.doReturn(deviceObject).`when`(testedRepo,
                PowerMockito.method(
                        MyClass::class.java,
                        "getDeviceObject"))
        val a = SaveCallback { // Callback handling here }
        // Calling REAL method of spy class. Here it fails
        myClassTest.persistDeviceData(DeviceInfo(), a)
        Assert.assertTrue(true)
    }

}
```

Test fails when calling real method on following line

> myClassTest.persistDeviceData(DeviceInfo(), a)

Here's the error stack trace

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.CannotStubVoidMethodWithReturnValue: 
>   'persistDeviceData' is a *void method* and it *cannot* be stubbed with a *return value*!
>   Voids are usually stubbed with Throwables:
>       doThrow(exception).when(mock).someVoidMethod();
>   If you need to set the void method to do nothing you can use:
>       doNothing().when(mock).someVoidMethod();
>   For more information, check out the javadocs for Mockito.doNothing().
>
> ---
>
> If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
>   Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
>   1. The method you are trying to stub is *overloaded*. Make sure you are calling the right overloaded version.
>   2. Somewhere in your test you are stubbing *final methods*. Sorry, Mockito does not verify/stub final methods.
>   3. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
>      - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
>   4. Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.

```
at MyClassTest.<init>(MyClass.kt:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at io.kotlintest.KTestJUnitRunner.<init>(KTestJUnitRunner.kt:9)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.createInstance(WhiteboxImpl.java:1414)
at org.powermock.reflect.internal.WhiteboxImpl.invokeConstructor(WhiteboxImpl.java:1262)
at org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox.invokeConstructor(Whitebox.java:497)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$1.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:101)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner$1.call(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:97)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.withContextClassLoader(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:132)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.createDelegate(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:96)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.DelegatingPowerMockRunner.<init>(DelegatingPowerMockRunner.java:64)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:165)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.createDelegatorFromClassloader(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:47)
at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.createTestDelegators(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:107)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:69)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:36)
at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question - I incorrectly user PowerMockito's .when() method. Here's the code that works:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass::class, DeviceObject::class)
class DeviceRepositoryImplTest{

    private val testedRepo = PowerMockito.spy(MyClass())
    private val deviceObject = PowerMockito.mock(DeviceObject())

    @Test
    fun persistDeviceData_ok(){
        // Mocking private method
        PowerMockito.`when`<ParseObject>(testedRepo,
            PowerMockito.method(
                        MyClass::class.java,
                            "getDeviceObject")).withNoArguments().thenReturn(deviceObject)

        // Creating callback for tested method
        val callback = SaveCallback {
            ...
        }

        ...

        testedRepo.persistDeviceData(DeviceInfo(), callback)

    }
```